# Can a non-const function be called using a non-const pointer and how the program will behave when two unique_ptrs point to the same objec?

Tags: c++, oop, c++17, unique-ptr, dynamic-cast

The first question:

Now I have two `unique_ptr`s (`ptrToBase` and `ptrToDerived`) pointing to the same object (made by `make_unique`). So is the program behavior undefined or how will it work on destroying the two pointers?

The second one:

the pointer `as_const(ptrToDerived)` is constatn. how `function2` can be called although it's a non-constant function

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
class Base{

    public:
    virtual void function()const{
        cout<<"\n"<<__FUNCSIG__;
    }

    virtual~Base(){cout<<"\n"<<__FUNCSIG__;}
};




class Derived : public Base
{

    public:
    int var{9};

    virtual void function()const override{
        cout<<"\n"<<__FUNCSIG__<<"\nvar: "<<var;
    }
    void function1()const{
        cout<<"\n"<<__FUNCSIG__;
    }

    void function2(){
        cout<<"\n"<<__FUNCSIG__;
    }

    virtual~Derived(){cout<<"\n"<<__FUNCSIG__;}
};



int main()
{

    //ptr of type Base* pointing to an object of type of Derived 
    unique_ptr<Base> ptrToBase {make_unique<Derived>()};

    unique_ptr<Derived> ptrToDerived {dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptrToBase.get())};
    if (ptrToDerived) ptrToDerived->function1();

    as_const(ptrToDerived)->function2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those aren't unique if more than one points to the same object. Smart pointers are about resource *ownership*. If you have more than one `std::unique_ptr` referring to the same object you have a *severe* code smell. I suspect `std::shared_ptr`s and `dynamic_pointer_cast` is what you *should* be using.

Comment: "So is the program behavior undefined..." as soon as one of them is destructed, and the other smart pointer is accessed or destructed.  "...or how will he work on destroying the two pointers?"  That's what `shared_ptr` is for.

Comment: @Eljay Since the two pointers won't be destructed before the line calling `function1`, how the line could work although `function1()` isn't constant

Comment: `const` functions can be called for `const` or non-const objects; non-const functions cannot be called for `const` objects.

Comment: @WhozCraig I used `shared_ptr`s and `make_shared` but the program takes a while before it teminates. I think there is undefined behavior too even if I used `shared_ptr`

Comment: If you properly use `dynamic_pointer_cast` that won't be the case. Handing a *raw* pointer to a freshly constructed smart pointer means that smart pointer at that moment own that resource *exclusively*. Your posted code of dynamic_cast ing the raw pointer out of a smart pointer to construct *another* smart pointer is flat wrong.

Comment: @EljaySorry I've updated the second question. Please see it

Comment: To what I was referring, [like this](https://ideone.com/31pVDl).

Comment: One question at a time please here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is the program behavior undefined or how will it work on destroying the two pointers?

Yes, it has UB because of the double destruction. Don't do this.

> the pointer as_const(ptrToDerived) is constatn. how function2 can be called although it's a non-constant function

`std::as_const` will make it a  `const std::unique_ptr<Derived>` not a `std::unique_ptr<const Derived>` which is why calling `function2()` works.

This will on the other hand not work:

```
unique_ptr<const Derived> ptrToDerived{dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptrToBase.get())};

ptrToDerived->function2();
```

Possible compiler output:

```
source>:41:29: error: passing 'const Derived' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

   41 |     ptrToDerived->function2();
```

Comment: Sorry I've updated the second question. Please see it

Comment: So `const unique_ptr<T> ptr` doesn't meant the object pointed to by ptr is constant, hence what does it mean

Comment: It means that `ptr` itself is `const` and you won't be able to assign a new pointer to it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Isn't what you talking about should be written as `unique_ptr<T> const ptr` or this is the case with raw pointers only

Comment: `const unique_ptr<T>` and `unique_ptr<T> const` are actually the same thing. `const` affects what's to the left of it - unless it's first, then it affects what's to the right of it. Messy indeed.

Checkout this example: https://godbolt.org/z/cdqrHX and this https://godbolt.org/z/taNRVy

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem of double-deletion a few ways.

If you know that you want the lifetime of the object to be controlled by one unique_ptr, you can make a simple observer_ptr which will hold a pointer but not attempt to destroy the object:

```
// a deleter that will not delete
struct no_delete
{
    template<class P> 
    void operator()(P*) const noexcept
    {
        // nothing;
    }
};

template<class T> 
using observer_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, no_delete>;
```

If you want the lifetime of the object to end when the last of the pointers goes out of scope, and you don't know which one will go out of scope first, then you'll want `std::shared_ptr`

https://godbolt.org/z/vrXzFT